# Cannot set java.io.tmpdir for Android sdkmanager

Tags: android-studio, jvm, jvm-arguments

I've installed Android Studio on a Fedora 25 system.  When I went to use the emulator and create a new virtual device, I was offered some options to download a system image.  This failed with the message that there is "no space left on device".

Since then, every time I go through the same steps, instead of getting to choose which image to download, I get "No system images available.  Are you connected to the internet?" -- I am.

I then tried to run `sdkmanager` directly, and it craps out with:

```
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Insufficient space for shared memory file:
   20622
Try using the -Djava.io.tmpdir= option to select an alternate temp location.
```

I presume this refers to `/tmp`, which is an in memory (`tmpfs`) filesystem with a 4GB upper bound, more or less none of which is in use.  I am fine using somewhere else if more space is needed.

The `sdkmanager` launch script mentions:

#

```
 Add default JVM options here. You can also use JAVA_OPTS and SDKMANAGER_OPTS to pass JVM options to this script.
DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS='"-Dcom.android.sdklib.toolsdir=$APP_HOME"'
```

I've tried three things in relation to this, using a location in a 100 GB filesystem that's half full:

- Set via `$_JAVA_OPTIONS`.  The JVM acknowledges this, but the app still fails
- Set via `$JAVA_OPTS` and `$SDKMANAGER_OPTS`.
- Edited directly into the `sdkmanager` launch script above.

None of these made any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deleting the installation (`~/Android`, `~/.AndroidStudio1.3`, etc.), setting `$_JAVA_OPTIONS`, then re-running `studio.sh`) solved this problem.

This implies the temp directory is being hardcoded somewhere when the app is run the first time.

Comment: I did almost the same thing.
I copied `AndroidStudio3.0` from another PC and inserted in `bin.studio.sh` the following line : `-Djava.io.tmpdir=/home/tmp`